# Wireframe and vertices have disappeared

Tags: vertices, wireframe

New to Blender, no idea what hotkey I've pushed. The wireframe/vertices in Edit Mode have all disappeared. Effectively, Object Mode and Edit Mode are now look identical. If I move to "Modelling", they're all available. Additionally, when I select an object in Object Mode, the orange border that appears is now no longer there.

I'm assuming there's some way to hide/unhide or a preference of some description but I've got no idea how to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably turned off overlays. See below:

[image: Overlays]